# svn ant make character uppercase

Tags: java, ant

I have a path with the following values:

`fullPath="https://..starturl/st1.txt,https://..beginurl/bg32.txt,https://..darkurl/dk17.txt"`

```
    <for list="${fullPath}" param="parsedName" >
           <sequential>             
            <echo message="@{parsedName}" />
            </sequential>
    </for>
```

I got the below result which is correct

```
https://..starturl/st1.txt
https://..beginurl/bg32.txt
https://..darkurl/dk17.txt
```

What I want is to make last word upper

```
https://..starturl/ST1.TXT
https://..beginurl/BG32.TXT
https://..darkurl/DK17.TXT
```

Comment: Consider using the ant script task to do the text manipulation - http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/script.html

Comment: @MichaelPeacock isnt there another way than using `<scriptt>`

Comment: @Moudiz, any specific reason for not willing to use `script`?

Comment: @Rao well task assigned to me without using script.